# how to set text in Searchview when listView item is clicked

Tags: android, textview, searchview

I am working with SearchView. When I write query in Searchview a list of items(Suggestions list) is apppeared. When i click the list item the text of list item does not show in Searchview. I have tried Suggestion listener but application stops working by this method.how can i show the text of clicked item in SearchView.
Also i have tried setquery() but it only work for first or some items and the is shown is SearchView when i click another item it stops the app.When I remove setQuery() it works fine but the name is not shown in SearchView. 
  here is some part of code.
CustomAdapter.java

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

TextView txtView = (TextView) ((MainActivity)c).findViewById(R.id.textView);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    txtView.setText("");
    SearchView sv=(SearchView) ((MainActivity)c).findViewById(R.id.sv);
    sv.setQuery(""+planets.get(pos).getName(),false);
    sv.clearFocus();
    String d=planets.get(pos).getPrice();
    int id1=planets.get(pos).getId();
    String text=planets.get(pos).getName();

    txtView.setText(id1 + System.getProperty ("line.separator") +text + System.getProperty ("line.separator") +d);

    planets.clear();
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

});

here is Debug error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.tutorials.hp.sqlitefilterlistview, PID: 22679
                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:260)
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:313)
                      at com.tutorials.hp.sqlitefilterlistview.mListView.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:106)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22679 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

it points to line CustomAdapter.java(106) which is

```
String d=planets.get(pos).getPrice();
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Also i have tried setQuery() but it only works for first or some items,
>   when i click another item it stops the app.

Yes, [it looks like](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setQuery(java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean)) `setQuery(text, false)` is what you need. Now, the fact that the app works for some items and for other crashes most probably it is not related to `setQuery(..)`.

For example if the `pos` variable exceeds the bounds of the `planets` list size, then a call to `planets.get(pos)` will fail with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but  check the stacktrace, it will tell you exactly why the app is crashing.

Comment: i have updated the question and add the debugg error. plz check if u can help

Comment: As initially assumed, the issue you are having is not caused by `setQuery(..)`. The app is crashing because the list is having only one item, but you are trying to retrieve the item situated on second position, which is the item with index 1. Remember in Java array and list indexes start from 0. 
From the code provided it is hard to figure out what's going wrong there, you have to debug yourself and see why the `pos` is bigger than the size of the list. But one suspicios statement is this: `planets.clear();`. Is it supposed to clear the list after the click?

Comment: yes planets.clear(); is used to  to clear the list after the click?

Comment: So on the second click is the list re-filled or empty? Because if it's empty and you are calling `planets.get(pos)` it will throw an exception like the one you are having.

Comment: before 2nd click  list is re filled. Because it is re filled  when i write query in searchView.